# Alterations to Tor and finding a way to run tests and simulations

Tags: deanonymization, traffic-analysis

For one of my assignments I have to conduct a research paper. I decided to propose a solution vulnerabilities TOR has with traffic analysis.

I'm suggesting adding in random delays,random hop count and random dummy data.

I'm aware of the impact this will have on the speed of the network, it's more of an ideal world scenario.

My question is there a way I could implement this and run some tests in order to provide me with some results proving that it's harder to de anonymise someone ?

Many thanks in advance, any help or advice is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can: actually, Tor code is *everything* the network relies and runs on. You should raise your own Directory servers and replace the standart ones in the source code [here](https://gitweb.torproject.org/tor.git/tree/src/or/fallback_dirs.inc)

Comment: Those are the fallback directory servers, not the directory authorities which you'd need to replace to run your own, distinct Tor network.

Comment: you need to replace these ones too AFAIK